# How to turn 'const boost::filesystem2::path' into 'const char *'?

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

How to turn 'const boost::filesystem2::path' into 'const char *'?

Comment: Do you expect the result to be compatible with the OS way of doing so? In particular, when the filename contains non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using [`path::string().c_str()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/reference.html#basic_path-observers)

Comment: It looks to me like string() returns a local copy so taking a copy of the char* pointer returned by this may not be usable.
So std::string s = path.string(); char* c = s.c_str(); instead